# VBA - Issues with show detail for Pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Sorry if there is a basic answer to this but I've been stumped on this for a while.  I have a pivot table which I want to show the detail of each cell in the second to last row between column D and the second to last column. The formula I wrote to do this isn't doing anything and I am not 100% sure why (I know I wrote it to do a different range just wanted to get something simpler working).  It could be that there is a problem with me defining the last column or I could just be completely on the wrong page with this.  Ideally each new page it would create would be named as the value of cell I2 on that page as well.  Please find my code below and thanks for your help.

```
'Define LastColumn
 LastColumn = sht.Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 'Define last row
 LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = "D" To LastColumn
Range(LastRow & i).Select
With Selection
Selection.ShowDetail = True
End With
Next i
```

Comment: `For i = "D" to LastColumn` can't be right - you can't iterate on the String "D", but you can on the number 4 corresponding to column D. But then you'd have to use `sht.Cells(LastRow - 1, i)` instead of `Range(LastRow & i)` - assuming you want the second to last row. And I'm assuming your iteration would stop at `LastColumn - 1`.

Comment: `For i = "D" to ...` , you mean `For i = 4 to ...` (since "D" is column 4)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've made the edits you suggested but I am still not having any luck